# Understanding neural network output >1 with sigmoid activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, sigmoid

I'm experimenting with a model combining a convolutional neural network with a linear model. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.experimental import WideDeepModel, LinearModel
```

```
num_classes = 1 ##(0='NO' or 1='YES')

cnn_model.Sequential()
cnn_model.add(Conv1D(20, 8, padding='same', activation='relu'))
cnn_model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
cnn_model.add(Dropout(0.6))
cnn_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid'))

linear_model = LinearModel()
combined_model = WideDeepModel(linear_model, cnn_model)
combined_model.compile(optimizer = ['sgd', 'adam'],
                            loss = ['mse','binary_crossentropy'], 
                         metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Performance is very good and everything seems to be going well until I sorted the predictions by `pval` and I can see there are predictions >1 even when I'm using **sigmoid** activation which is I thought was supposed to bring everything between 0 and 1, and no activation function for the linear model (but inputs are all scaled 0-1):

```
pred = [ 1 if a > threshold else 0 for a in combined_model.predict([dplus_test, X_test])]
pv = combined_model.predict([dplus_test, X_test])
pval = [a[0] for a in pv]
```

```
    true    pred    pval    dplus
1633    1   1   1.002850    15.22404
1326    1   1   1.001444    10.34983
1289    1   1   1.001368    10.03043
1371    1   1   1.000986    10.74037
1188    1   1   1.000707    8.902
```

I checked on the other end of the data, and those predictions are as I expected, always >0.

```
    true    pred    pval    dplus
145     0   0   0.000463    1.81635
383     0   0   0.001023    3.24982
1053    0   0   0.001365    7.22535
```

This is not a problem so far, nothing crashes and I'm happy with the performance.

I would like to know if my understanding of the sigmoid activation function is wrong or if there is something in the Combined model that allows values to go above 1 and whether I can trust these results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your sigmoid is defined only on the output of the `Deep` model and the way the `WideDeepModel` combines the two model's outputs is by adding them (and your `Wide` linear model can have arbitrary output). Since you include both `mse` and `binary_crossentropy` in your loss, the combined model actually learns to output values close to the expected range.

If you had just `binary_crossentropy`, you would probably see values much larger than 1, since the formula for the loss is `-p * log(q)` where `q` is the output of your network, you could make the loss arbitrarily small by increasing `q` indefinitely, which doesn't happen when your output is bounded.

The `WideDeepModel` has an additional attribute `activation` (see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/experimental/WideDeepModel)) where you can define the activation function of the whole model. If you want to squeeze the output between 0 and 1, set it to `sigmoid`.

```
combined_model = WideDeepModel(linear_model, cnn_model, activation='sigmoid')
```

Also as a final note, in my experience, combining mean squared error and binary crossentropy like this doesn't make much sense, in practice you'd choose one or the other.